# Need to recover BIGSERIAL "primary key" value from an Informix stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures

I have the following Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE eukno(pk BIGINT, requestee VARCHAR(20))
RETURNING BIGINT;
DEFINE eunid BIGINT;
INSERT INTO ent_uniq (eunid, eunreq) VALUES (pk, requestee);
RETURN eunid;
END PROCEDURE;
```

I get the value inserted into the table but I need the primary key value `eunid` to be returned for the exact value during this insert. `eunid` is a `BIGSERIAL` primary key with a start value of 9999000000, so on my first insert, `eunid` automates to produce 9999000001
The Stored Procedure is executed with parameters (0, 'username') and the primary is automatically increased by one. Need to retrieve exact uniq eunid at time of insert as many users will request this ID in a single moment.

Comment: I modified the procedure to as follows:

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE eukno(pk BIGINT)
RETURNING BIGINT;
DEFINE eunid BIGINT;

INSERT INTO ent_uniq (eunid) VALUES (pk); 
RETURN DBINFO('serial8');

END PROCEDURE;

Comment: With this change however, I still 0, the value of the insert I specified, not the actual value the database generated.

Comment: Please transfer your comments into an update to the question (and then delete the comments).  You can then format the code correctly.

Comment: Yes, thanks Jonathan. I worked it out eventually yesterday and our network crashed while I was clicking on "Answer Your Question". Sorry for wasting your time. Nice to get confirmation though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DBINFO('serial8')` function returns the value of the key for the last SERIAL8 column.  You're inserting into a BIGSERIAL; you need to use `DBINFO('bigserial')` instead.

```
SQL[2163]: CREATE PROCEDURE eukno(pk BIGINT, requestee VARCHAR(20))
         > RETURNING BIGINT;
         > INSERT INTO ent_uniq (eunid, eunreq) VALUES (pk, requestee);
         > RETURN DBINFO('bigserial');
         > END PROCEDURE;
SQL[2164]: execute procedure eukno(57, 'varieties');
57
SQL[2165]: execute procedure eukno(0, 'boredom');
58
SQL[2166]:
```

Note that SERIAL is a 4-byte serial type; both SERIAL8 and BIGSERIAL support 8-byte ranges of serial numbers, but BIGSERIAL is the better type to use (for a variety of reasons).

You might also note that in your code, the local variable `eunid` is both completely separate from the `ent_uniq.eunid` column (it happens to have the same name as the column, but that's all), and is either uninitialized when returned or unused.